# Calling webservice from javascript on android

Tags: android

How to call a webservice from javascript on android?

My html file is in `assest/www` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so - you would like to call AJAX web service from the JavaScript in a web page? This is not dependent (or almost not) on the used web browser. The same JavaScript code will work on Android, iPhone or desktop browser.

For good AJAX tutorial see there: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=425820

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) You can't run Javascript in an Android Application!